# express app.get with multiple fields

Tags: node.js, http, express

```
app.get('/api/advancedSearch/:id/:page_no/:exact_phrase?/:exclude_words?'
,function (req,res) 
{ //body });
```

I'm trying to create an app.get as shown above, I have no problems with the first couple of fields, the problem arises with the "exact_phrase" and "exclude words" fields. These are supposed to be lists and if both of them are passed I have no problems getting them.

What does cause problems is that sometimes one or both of those fields might not be present and I still need to get it. I can't seem to be able to design the app.get for that.

Is there a way to design the app.get or send the request such that I can do this?

Comment: It seems like you'd be better off using  [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) instead of `req.params`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, optional parts of the URL work a lot better in the query string because they are self identifying which ones are present (since they are named parameters rather than only identified by URL position).

URL path segments in Express route matching are order specific and you can't have any sequence you want of optional parameters because that just isn't deterministic for what was passed.  The Express route matching algorithm by itself isn't as flexible or powerful as you seem to want.

You have several options:

1. Leave the `:exact_phrase` and `:exclude_words` out of the route definition and then just do your own URL parsing in the route handler to see exactly what is there.  In this way you can adjust to any format you want.
2. Put all parameters that might be in a different order or might be optional as query parameters rather that path segments in the URL and then use `req.query` to see exactly what was present in the URL.  Query parameters are optional and can be in any order.

This last option would be like this:

```
// url: /api/advancedSearch/123/4?exact_phrase=foo&exclude_words=cat,dog
app.get('/api/advancedSearch/:id/:page_no/', function(req,res) {
    var excludeWords = [];
    if (req.query.exclude_words) {
        excludeWords = req.query.exclude_words.split(",");
    }
    var exactPhrase = req.query.exact_phrase || "";

    // do the rest of your processing here

});
```

FYI, it makes sense conceptually that optional arguments should be in the queryString, not in the core URL path.  Since query string parameters are self-identifying it makes it a lot less ambiguous which ones are present and which ones are not.  If you have optional path segments in the URL, then you have to somehow invent some sort of system for identifying which path segment is present and what its meaning is.  Because this is entirely application and context specific, Express can't do that for you automatically.